# Linear if and only if preserves lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

As basic as this might sound, how can I prove that a map between vector spaces is linear if and only if it preserves lines therein?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take a translation - this map isn't linear

Comment: by "lines" do you mean all points $a + tb$ for $t \in F$ where $F$ is the field of the vector space? I.e. show that if $T(a + tb) = T(a) + t T(b)$ for all $a, b \in V$ and all $t \in F$ then F is a linear transformation?

Comment: The zero map "preserves" nothing ...

Comment: I take it this means "maps affine lines to affine lines".

Comment: You still have to assume that $\{ 0 \}$ is a degenerated line ...

Comment: And it is obviously wrong, as those are exactly the (bijective) affine maps

Comment: $\{0\} *is* a degenerate line!

Comment: I know. The point is what op knows or rather not

Comment: Well, clearly we don't want to (try to) prove that all affine transformations are linear. I guessed at what OP meant, an interpretation that's at least true. But he'll have to let us know what exactly "line" and "preserve" mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that by a "line" you mean 'affine lines": all points $a + tb$ for $t \in$ the field $F$ of the vector space, for some $a, b \in V$; and that a map $T$ "preserves" the line if $T$ transforms it into the affine line $T(a) + tT(b), t \in F$ in the image.

*Be aware, though, that this is a special of "preserving lines". In its standard use, that phrase means: the image of a line under the transformation is a line, and that's a broader class of transformations. These "line preserving transformations" have the special property that the image of a line through the origin is another line through the origin. See the last paragraph for more on this. Essentially we're just showing that two different definitions of "linear transformation" are equivalent.*

If $T$ is a linear tranformation on a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ then clearly it preserves lines -- $T(a + tb) = T(a) + t T(b)$ for all $a, b \in V$ and all $t \in F$. So we need to prove the other direction.

So suppose that $T(a + tb) = T(a) + t T(b)$ for all $a, b \in V$ and all $t \in F$.

First, note that $T(0) = 0$: $T(0) = T(0 + 1*0) = T(0) + 1*T(0) = T(0) + T(0)$, so subtracting $T(0)$ from both sides gives $0 = T(0)$.

Suppose $a, b \in V$. Then $T(a+b) = T(a + 1*b) = T(a) + T(b)$, so $T$ preserves $+$.

Finally, for $t \in F$ and $a \in V$, we have $T(ta) = T(0 + ta) = T(0) + tT(a) = tT(a)$.

So T is linear.

Note, though, that more generally, *affine transformations* preserve lines but certainly are not linear. Given $a \in V, a \neq 0$, the affine transformation $T \colon v \mapsto a + v$ "preserves lines" but is not a linear transformation ($T(0) = a$).

Comment: You assume $T$ is linear to prove that $T$ is linear ...

Comment: Essentially. It's just showing that the two definitions are equivalent. (What else could it mean, assuming what's to be proved is true?)

Comment: No. Your idea what "preserving lines" means is way too strong. Also, how could you "show" that preserving lines implies linearity and at the same time admit that there are non linear functions which preserve lines?

Comment: Upfront I said what I assume the term "preserving" has to mean. The OP seems to mean that guessed definition, as he deemed the answer correct. What would you propose I do, delete the answer?

Comment: Note the last paragraph, and the qualifications in the first paragraph. What would you change or add?

Comment: I added *2nd paragraph*. Clear enough?

Comment: Just leave the first sentence, the 3rd and the last paragraphs. The rest is tautological.

Comment: The rest may be elementary but it isn't at all tautological, & the 2nd paragraph is neither, so I won't be doin' that, no.

Answer (score 0):

A line is a collection of vectors defined by taking scalar multiples of a single spanning vector. Since the function is linear, whatever it does to that "basis" vector for the line, it does to the entire line by linearity.

On the other hand, if a map behaves in this way, sending all lines through the origin to other lines, then it sounds like it must satisfy the definition of linearity $f(0) = 0$, since it must go through the origin, and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, since otherwise it could "break" a line. Similar reasoning for $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ - if scalar multiples did not pass through $f$, it sounds like "lines" could change slopes or in fact be curves.